# Angular2: navigate to a route and pop back to the root of the pushState stack

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart, angular2-routing

Using Angular2 routing, how can I navigate to some route, while having the `pushState` pop all the way back to the root?

I looked into the `router.navigate([...])` method of `Router`, but didn't find it there.

For example, in Dart's `route_hierarchical` `Router`, I could do
`router.go('login',{},replace: true,startingFrom:router.root);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Angular2 provides this functionality in it's Router, here's a temporary workaround:

```
abstract class Hist {
  static int _initialLength;
  // Call this ASAP when app starts.
  static void setAsInitialLength() {
    _initialLength = window.history.length;
  }
  static Future goBackToRoot() async {
    Completer completer = new Completer();
    window.history.go(-(window.history.length-_initialLength));
    Timer.run((){
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
await Hist.goBackToRoot();
router.navigate(['/Main',{}]);
```